# c++ missing data while reading from file

Tags: c++

Hi guys sry to trouble you. I have 2 problems.

1. I having problem printing out the last data in my file
2. How can i print out only certain row start with the username

Data:

```
tom12:Miscellaneous:-30.52:20JAN15
ben23:Utility Bill:-56.50:17JAN15
tom12:Child Needs:-80.95:15JAN15
tom12:Baby needs:-20.9:18JAN15
ben23:Phone Bill:-35.90:12JAN14
ben23:Housing Bill:-192.88:01JAN15
```

Code:

```
string line;
ifstream file("expenses.txt");
double totalNegative = 0;
double totalPositive = 0;
while(getline(file, line))
{
    stringstream linestream(line);
    string data1;
    string data2;
    double data3;
    string data4;
    getline(linestream, data1, ':');
    getline(linestream, data2, ':');              
    linestream >>data3;
    getline(linestream, data4, ':');
    cout << data2 << " $" << data3 << " " << data4 << " "<< endl;
}
```

Results:

```
Miscellaneous $-30.52
Utility Bill $-56.50
Child Needs $-80.95
Baby needs $-20.9
Phone Bill $-35.90
Housing Bill $-192.88
```

The results are missing the dates at the last column. And how do i print out only "tom12" which is the user. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
{
    stringstream linestream(line);
    string data1;
    string data2;
    double data3;
    string data4;
    getline(linestream, data1, ':');
    getline(linestream, data2, ':');              
    linestream >>data3;
    linestream.ignore(1); // ignore ':'
    getline(linestream, data4, ':');
    cout << data1 << " $" << data3 << " " << data4 << " "<< endl;
}
```

[Live code here](http://ideone.com/Q0ySlM)

- Adding `linestream.ignore(1);` would ignore 1 character. Otherwise when you try to read the date until `:`, you end up reading nothing as the first character is `:`
- Change data2 to data1 to get first name
- To print conditionally, use an if before cout statement

`if(data1 == "tom12") cout << data1 << " $" << data3 << " " << data4 << " "<< endl;`

Comment: An explanation of why those changes are relevant would be useful.

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks. Added details. I accidentally hit some key (possibly ctrl + enter) and my answer was submitted before completion.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
linestream >>data3;
```

you still have a colon plus the last token in the stream. For example, in the case of the first line

```
tom12:Miscellaneous:-30.52:20JAN15
```

what you have left in the stream is

```
:20JAN15
```

because you consumed everything up to and including `-30.52`. In this state,

```
getline(linestream, data4, ':');
```

will give you everything before the next `:`, which is the empty string.

Depending on how you want to handle misshapen data, there are several ways to resolve it; perhaps the easiest is

```
getline(linestream, data4, ':'); // consume that colon (and possibly things left before it)
getline(linestream, data4);      // then take the rest of the line.
```